# Random number generator(RNG) on Solana program

Tags: anchor, solana-program, transactions

I'd like to know the way to get a lot of random numbers in a function on Solana Rust program. I know the way to get random number in a function but not sure if it works to get multiple numbers.

Comment: Why not use the same way you used to generate random number for one function using the same logic to get multiple random number in that function itself

Comment: The RNG function used the block timestamp to generate the random number, so in a function, the all numbers are same.

Comment: You can use Switchboard VRF to get random no as well

Comment: There is an awesome detailed blogpost on this topic here https://www.daoplays.org/blog/random_numbers